# Correctness of complexity analysis of recursive algorithm

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, computational-complexity, recursive-algorithms

Given following recursive equation:

$$T(n) = T(n-3) + \Theta(1)$$

Is it correct that this equation is O(1)?

Comment: Is it assumed, here, that $\Theta(1)$ is uniform over $n$?  That is, that $\{T(n)-T(n-3)\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is bounded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You apply the recursive equation approximately $n/3$ times to get down to the base case, and each time you apply the equation you get a $\Theta(1)$ contribution. Thus the complexity is $T(n) = \Theta(n)$.

Comment: You're right. What a pity of myself :/. The first part vanishes after (n-1)/3 recursions. So generalizing the equation to $$T(n) = T(n-3k) + k \Theta(1)$$. For k=(n-1)/3 the first part vanishes to an O(1) and the second part ((n-1)/3 \Theta(1)) is an \Theta(n) so overall it's a Theta(n)